# Validate recursive union with pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

Consider the following listing:

```py
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Tuple, Union

@dataclass
class A:
    name: str
    collection: Tuple[Union["A", int], ...]

A.__pydantic_model__.update_forward_refs()

# Does not work:
c = A("name", (A("a", tuple()), 42,))
```

When an instance of `A` is created, validation fails with:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for A
collection -> 0
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
collection -> 0
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
```

The issue here is that `pydantic` does not consider `A` to be a valid item when validating an instance of `A`. For instance, if I remove the `A` item, validation passes just fine:

```py
# Works fine:
c = A("name", (42,))
```

Is this a bug? How do I validate recursive unions with `pydantic`?

Comment: I could not reproduce the error you mentioned and the instance was created successfully. I used python `3.9.7` and pydantic `1.8.2`. What versions are you using?

Comment: I updated pydantic to `1.9.0` and the error appeared. I guess something changed between those two versions.